# Is there any reason why a camera's matrixworldinverse won't update when using trackball controls?

Tags: three.js, trackball

I'm viewing a scene using threejs and the trackball camera. I try to get the view matrix from the camera, but its matrixworldinverse isn't updating. I do call updateMatrixWorld in my render function. The matrixworld is updating, just not the inverse. Any ideas why?

Comment: To put this older question to rest, these days it seems THREE.js always keeps camera.matrixWorldInverse up-to-date noted in three.js r.95

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it yourself:

```
camera.matrixWorldInverse.getInverse( camera.matrixWorld );
```

Make sure `camera.matrixWorld` is updated first. Note that by default, it is automatically updated by the renderer.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks WestLangley, just thought it was weird because it was working in this example: http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_trackball.html

Comment: Hmmm. Something is fishy. Do you have `camera.matrixAutoUpdate = false`? Maybe you can track this issue down...